# How to Subtract a Date value in a variable

Tags: shell, date, unix, compare, subtraction

I have a problem to create a script. My problem is when trying to subtract a date. In my script I pass a date with the format dd/mm/yyyy as parameter and I need to compare with files in a directory that has the date in the filename. The date can be the actul or until 5 days before the day passed as parameter. My question is, how can I create an if condition for example that will compare the date as parameter and the last 5 days before it with the date that is specified in the filename ? I already searched in every place how can I do it and nothing could help me.

Thanks for now.

Jairo.

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences) should help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your requirement, but this may help you(not the best of solutions)
assuming the file names are in format:  file_11092013 , file_01092013

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSED_DATE=$1

date_diff() {
    d1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
    d2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
    echo $(( (d2 - d1) / 86400 ))
}

for file in `ls /home/mvaidya/test`
do
    curr_file=`echo $file | awk 'BEGIN {FS="_"} {print $NF}'`
    day1=`echo $curr_file| cut -c1-2`
    month1=`echo $curr_file| cut -c3-4`
    year1=`echo $curr_file| cut -c5-8`

    day2=`echo $PASSED_DATE| cut -c1-2`
    month2=`echo $PASSED_DATE| cut -c4-5`
    year2=`echo $PASSED_DATE| cut -c7-10`

    no_of_days=$( date_diff "$month2/$day2/$year2" "$month1/$day1/$year1" )

    if [ $no_of_days -ge 5 ] ; then
        echo "File "$file" more than 5 days old."   
    else 
        echo "File "$file" less than 5 days old."
    fi  

done
```

Eg:

```
$./exp1.sh 01/09/2013
File file_11092013 more than 5 days old.

$./exp1.sh 10/09/2013
File file_11092013 less than 5 days old.
```